# Validation function, and looping through objects to find better performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, object

I have a validate function that does validation, so far the code below does what I want, pass in all the $('.required') classes then loop through them to check each of their values. If none of them equal an empty string enable the next button once all fields have at least one character.

Was just curious if there is a better way to accomplish the same task, or if anybody had any speed performance enhancements would be also great thank you!

```
validate : function (requiredArray) {
            var valueObj = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < requiredArray.length; i++) {
                valueObj[i] = 'input#'+requiredArray[i].id;
                $(valueObj[i]).on("keyup mouseup", function (e) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(valueObj).length; j++) {
                        if($(valueObj[j]).val() !== '') {
                            $('.btn-success.nextButton').removeClass('disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('.btn-success.nextButton').addClass('disabled');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should only define the handler function once, not every time through the loop, since it doesn't have any dependencies on the iteration variable.

Comment: You're adding event handlers every time you validate? I'd wonder why you're doing that. You're re-running `Object.keys()` on every iteration of the loop... that's terribly expensive compared to caching it. I'd also wonder why you're using a plain Object instead of an Array in the first place. You're doing repeated DOM selection inside the inner loop too. Terribly expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a common class `required` for all your inputs then you can try this:

```
validate: function() {
  var $inputs = $('input.required'),
      $button = $('.btn-success.nextButton'),
      hasEmpty = $inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).length;

  $inputs.on('keyup mouseup', function() {
    if (hasEmpty) return false;
    $button.removeClass('disabled');
  });
}
```

I'm not sure what your structure is but you should separate the events from the validation logic, for example:

```
var $inputs = $('input.required'),
    $button = $('.btn-success.nextButton');

function validate() {   
  return $inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).length;  
}    

$inputs.on('keyup mouseup', function() {   
  if (!validate()) return false;   
  $button.removeClass('disabled');  
});
```

Id's should be used sparingly, classes are more convenient.

Comment: maybe I am doing something wrong but it instantly enables the next button

Comment: console.log(hasEmpty); returns 2

Comment: @1337: See update, that should work. Just make sure your `button` is has the disabled class to start with.

Comment: You should think about separating the events from the function anyway. Check edit.

Comment: the value I get from $inputs.filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).length; is 2 for some reason, and the button is disabled by default

Comment: Then wouldn't I want to reassign hasEmpty on every keyup mouseup? Cause right now it doesn't re-enable the next button

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggest you separate the logic from the events, like in the code I posted. I thought you were calling `validate` on the inputs somewhere else.

Comment: Now it's just enabling by default even after I separated the logic: CMS.validate() actually returns the value 2 so in the if I modified it so that it was greater than 0 that kinda worked until I went back to the first required field and deleted the text, thus not disabling the button again...

Comment: this is how I got it to work:
$inputs.on('keyup mouseup', function() {
            if (CMS.validate()) {
                $('.btn-success.nextButton').addClass('disabled');  
                return false; 
            }   
            $('.btn-success.nextButton').removeClass('disabled');  
        });

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

```
$inputs.on('keyup mouseup', function() {  
    if (CMS.validate()) {
        $('.btn-success.nextButton').addClass('disabled');  
        return false; 
    }   
    $('.btn-success.nextButton').removeClass('disabled');  
        });
```